# Group replication ports issues

Tags: mysql, replication

What should be the ports for group replication if we are implementing group replication on three different MySQL servers? The `my.cnf` for the first server is

```
port=3306
loose-group_replication_local_address= "x.x.x.x:3307"
loose-group_replication_group_seeds= "x.x.x.x:3307,x.x.x.x:3307,x.x.x.x:3307"
```

For the second server the settings are same and I have changed the IP's in `loose-group_replication_local_address` accordingly, but I am facing this error when running `start GROUP_REPLICATION`:

> [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 3307'

Does any one know the solution?

Comment: Are you in the same machine with different network interfaces or in different machines? Is there any other error in the log? If you are on different machines, are the machines accessible among themselves?

Comment: i am on different machine and yes the machines are accessible among themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In the manuel they advise to use port 33061. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-replication-configuring-instances.html :

> "The recommended port for group_replication_local_address is 33061"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use same data inside databases between hosts, Make mysqldump from master and import all data to slave, after I configured slave and it works.